# Rails page cache with redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, redis

Has anyone used redis to store the cached html files created by Rails page caching?

I have multiple servers all storing their cache files on a mounted drive but there are latency problems that can't easily be resolved.  I can't store the cache files on each machine because I dont have a way to invalidate cache across machines.

Comment: I'd imagine something like this is more likely to exist with memcached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page caching will always write to the file system. Look into using action caching or fragment caching.

Here's the section on memcached from the Rails guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memcachestore

You'll need this gem if you want to stick with Redis:

https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store